# SSO Implementation - Any IDP Simulator available?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I am planning a SSO implementation using SAML 2.0. It is going to be SP (Force.com) Initiated authentication. I wanted to know if any SSO IDP simulator is available from AppXchange (preferred over Java based tools) to understand the implementation before trying it out with Enterprise IDP (ADFS in my case).

Comment: Do you have a test Enterprise IDP to work with or only the production IDP?

Comment: No only the production IDP ....

Answer (score 6):

You can set up another Salesforce org (e.g. a developer edition) to be your IDP - that's how I got to grips with it originally.  There's a wiki article that guides you through the whole process at:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Implementing_Single_Sign-On_Across_Multiple_Organizations

Comment: Thanks, very useful..I have 2 questions:[1] How do I use "User Name" instead of "Federation Id" (post talks on Federation Id) to authenticate. [2] In my SP ORG I provided the Federation Id to just One User and used the same Federation Id for one of the IDP users, the Logon to SP ORG as the user was successful; others are not incl Admin, how to solve this?

Comment: I don't think you can authenticate via User Name in this case, as Salesforce usernames have to be unique across all orgs, therefore you can't have the same username in the IDP and SP.

Comment: Another excellent Tool is Axiom which acts as an IDP and can be used to login to Salesforce with Federated Authentication. You may find it at the below URL:

http://axiomsso.herokuapp.com/SamlIdpHome.action

I have not tried it but thought it would be useful for other looking for similar setup.

Comment: Another useful post that explains "My Domain", "Redirection to SSO Login Page", "Skipping IDP Authentication". URL: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11713/how-does-a-user-with-saml-sso-get-redirected-to-idp-login-page

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using Elastic SSO to do this. A lot of good documentation on Elastic SSO for Salesforce SP SSO integration.